# gRPC message exceeds maximum size 4194304: 5145024 java

Tags: java, spring, network-programming, grpc, grpc-java

On grpc client I am getting this error after calling the rpc method in server.
I am using grpc-spring-boot-starter (java). Please tell me how to increase response size.

```
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:262)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:243)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:156)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you are using official grpc library then create client in following way.

```
ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 9089).usePlaintext().maxInboundMessageSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE).build();

productsBlockingStub prodStub = productsGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
```

You can refer the grpc project [here](https://github.com/deepakchandh/gRPC-java-implementation). Just add modification formaxInboundMessageSize

- If you are using grpc-client-spring-boot-starter then you can either.

```
@GrpcClient("greeting-service")
    private GreetingServiceGrpc.GreetingServiceBlockingStub greetingServiceBlockingStub;

    greetingServiceBlockingStub = greetingServiceBlockingStub.withMaxInboundMessageSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    greetingServiceBlockingStub = greetingServiceBlockingStub.withMaxOutboundMessageSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Or add this in props.

```
grpc.client.greeting-service.max-inbound-message-size=9155241000
grpc.client.greeting-service.package-max-inbound-message-size=9155241000
grpc.client.greeting-service.server.max-inbound-message-size=9155241000
```